# Achievements hint when putting a bounty on a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I recently put a 50 rep bounty on one of my questions, and today when I looked at the achievements menu item to the right of the "Stack Exchange" I saw a red -40 as one of the items. I know now that was simply due to the minus 50 rep bounty + two upvotes, but my first reaction was *Gasp, why so many downvotes!?!?!* It took me a couple minutes to make the connection.

The SE system seems to lump all rep gains and deductions together by Today, Yesterday, and Last 7 days. My question is, should bounty rep deductions appear in this manner? I do not see rep deducted/offered as a bounty as a bad thing--quite the opposite. However, semantically, the negative rep reflected in the Achievements area is a reflection of having bad questions or answers.

Am I the only one who feels this way? Would it perhaps be good to notate rep deductions due to bounties some way?

Comment: Yes, Recent Achievements is meant as a summary only when it comes to reputation. Detailed breakup of your rep can be found in the [Reputation section](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/83636/jeff-clark?tab=reputation) of your profile's Activity page. On another note, where does it tell you that rep deducted as a bounty is a bad thing? It merely shows all deducted rep in red and all added rep in green, which I find perfectly consistent and making sense.

Comment: It semantics. A red negative in modern society is usually a bad thing. Probably 99% of the time. That is why it threw me for a loop for a few minutes

Comment: Well, as far as the rep points are concerned, any deduction is bad, so there you are. You can see that the detailed Reputation page follows the same principle showing the values: all deductions are red, all additions green. Same with the reputation graph: the columns above the base line are green and below those below red. Colour scheme is consistent. In order to tell *real* bad deductions from good ones you just need to take a look at the detailed breakup to see what's what.

Answer (score 1):

I'm OK with this appearing* in the Achievements list, but it would be nice if it showed a "Bounty Started" description (or something similar), instead of just a raw negative amount:

[image: Capture]

I do see how a sudden -50 might be momentarily concerning.

---

<sub>* On meta.SE: [Ignore the rep change caused by placing bounties in the achievements reputation indicator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209467)</sub>